# Calculate the size of a list

Tags: python, list, size

I am trying to implement a function in Python which returns the size of a list. At the beginning the list=[0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]. I want to remove all of the 0s before calculating the size so it should be like this:

```
def cardl(list):
for j in range(0,10):
    if list[j]==0:
        list.remove(list[j])
        return len(e[g])
```

The problem is that instead of returning 1 at the end, it returns  9. Surely I have made some mistake in the loop.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Please don't post code with tab characters - it messes up the indentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're returning too early in your code and also modifying the list while iterating over it is not a good idea.

By the way an easier solution is:

```
>>> lis = [0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
>>> len(lis) - lis.count(0)
1
```

Comment: Great thanks ! I'm still having problem with return in Python. And does it work if the list is in this form List=[[0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]], it should then return 2 to me ?

Comment: @user3013792 For nested list you need something like: `sum(len(x) - x.count(0) for x in lis)`

Answer (score 3):

There's always the standard `sum` idiom:

```
sum(1 for x in lst if x != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using some of python's builtins:

```
    len(filter(None,list))
```